# Limits for Spotipy?

Tags: python, spotipy

I am trying to get a list of all my saved songs using current_user_saved_tracks(), but the limit is 20 tracks. Is there any way to access all 1000+ songs I have on m account?

Answer (score 3):

The [signature](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/c927f02c1caa5dafe9ac942aba0d019abd364db0/spotipy/client.py#L1164) is as follows:

```
def current_user_saved_tracks(self, limit=20, offset=0)
```

The [official Spotify API reference (beta)](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference-beta/#endpoint-get-users-saved-tracks) says that the maximum is `limit=50`. So, in a loop, call `current_user_saved_tracks`, but increment the `offset` by `limit` each time:

```
def get_all_saved_tracks(user, limit_step=50):
    tracks = []
    for offset in range(0, 10000000, limit_step):
        response = user.current_user_saved_tracks(
            limit=limit_step,
            offset=offset,
        )
        print(response)
        if len(response) == 0:
            break
        tracks.extend(response)
    return tracks
```

Loop until you get an empty response or an exception. I'm not sure which one.

If you don't have to worry about the user deciding to add a saved track *while* you are retrieving them, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the default argument is `limit=20`. You could set a higher limit with the following code:

```
current_user_saved_tracks(limit=50)
```

Or you could set an offset to get the 20 next tracks:

```
current_user_saved_tracks(offset=20)
```

Source: https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.14.0/?highlight=current_user_saved#spotipy.client.Spotify.current_user_saved_tracks